# NSObjects to URLs mapping

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I have an issue with NSObjects to URLs mapping. 
I followed the documentation and I get that :

```
[map from:[Foo class] name:@"foo" toURL:@"tt://detailedfoo/foo/(fooId)"];   

[map from:@"tt://detailedfoo/foo/(initWithFoo:)" toSharedViewController:[DetailedFooController class]];   

for (Foo* foo in foos)   
{   
    [items addObject:[TableFooItem itemWithTitle:nil  
caption:foo.title   
                                            text:foo.text   
                                             URL:[foo URLValueWithName:@"foo"]]];  
}
```

When my controller pushed, the "initWithFoo" method called but the Foo object belongs to NSCFString class and not Foo class.
If anyone has an idea, I take it !
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same name between the URL map and your invocation of URLValueWithName:. In this case:

```
[foo URLValueWithName:@"foo"]
```

This will check the url map, find the `@"foo"` name in the map, and then create the following url path for a Foo object with `fooId = 3`:

```
@"tt://detailedfoo/foo/3"
```

Comment: I use the same name between the URL map and the invocation of URLValueWithName but my Foo object is still nil.

Comment: It might also make a difference that your url is `"tt://detailedthing//foo/(initWithFoo:)"`, whereas it should probably be `"tt://detailedthing/foo/(initWithFoo:)"`. Note: one less forward slash.

Comment: I agree. I have "[foo URLValueWithName:@"foo"]" and "tt://detailedfoo/foo/(initWithFoo:)" but my Foo object is still nil.

Comment: `tt://detailedthing/` should also be `tt://detailedfoo/`

Comment: Thanks ! it works but I have another issue. My app crash when I try to access at my Foo object's properties => "unrecognized selector sent to instance"